# Add the SUM of a Column in mySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How would i add the sum of a column in mysql?

Here's my code:

```
$add = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(rsvp) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE rsvp > 0;")or die(mysql_error());
```

when i echo it, it gives me a Resource id #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up figuring it out.

```
$add = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(rsvp) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE rsvp >= 1;")or die(mysql_error());
list ( $rsvp_total ) = mysql_fetch_array($add); 

echo $rsvp_total;
```

Answer (score 2):

try this instead

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(rsvp) as sum FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE rsvp > 0") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
echo $row['sum'];
```

I recommend looking up more on how to use PHP and MySQL together possibly from one of these sites:
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php
- http://www.youtube.com/user/phpacademy - this one is pretty nooby but it does cover everything from pagination to image uploads and beyond. a good place to start I guess.

Comment: I wouldn't recomment naming the column 'sum' since it is a keyword as well. Also, www.php.net is a fine resource for finding information about PHP and MySQL.

Comment: W3Schools yikes no! Have them read the official PHP docs instead! http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

Comment: yeah i don't know why I didn't say that :-(

Comment: @kylestevenson: You can edit your answer and add any more info you think may be useful.

Comment: There you go, hope that helps more

Answer (score 1):

[`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query) returns a resource, not a value.  You need to use another function, such as [`mysql_fetch_row`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_row) to access the value it contained:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(rsvp) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE rsvp > 0;") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result); // get an array containing the value of the first row of the above query
$sum = (int) $row[0]; // get an integer containing the value of the first (and, here, only) item in that row
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and you use mysql_fetch_array to fetch a row from that resource.

```
$resource = mysql_query( ... );
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resource))
{
  $add = $row[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem,

Note: Undefined index: sum in D:\xampp\htdocs\demo-shop\cart.php on line 9

```
$sum_query= "SELECT sum(Prod_Tot) as sum FROM cart WHERE Prod_Tot > 0"; 
$sum_query_res  = mysql_query($sum_query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($sum_query_res);
echo $row['sum'];
```

If I put `echo $row['0'];` instead of `echo $row['sum'];` then it is ok.

Comment: Try 

$sum_query= "SELECT sum(Prod_Tot) as 'sum' FROM cart WHERE Prod_Tot > 0";

Answer (score 0):

This is short and simple try it

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(rsvp) as sum FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE rsvp > 0") or die(mysql_error());
```

$record = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
echo $record['sum'];